# AutoFilter in Macro does only apply when I go into Excel after running it open the filter options and click ok

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter out all Data where my used VLookup doesn't find a value so, in the German version this means that in these columns is writen #NV. I tried to do this by using an AutoFilter that shows all data not equaling #NV. After running the macro the filter is applied but the data is not filtered, I have to go into the sheet open the filter options and press ok then the filter is applied. My code for the Filter is:

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
ActiveSheet.range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>#NV", Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
```

[After running the macro with the code above before pressing ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUbxn.png)

[After pressing ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJo2w.png)

What is also weird I also filter for Data equaling #NV in the same Macro there the filter works just fine. Here is my code for that part:

```
ActiveSheet.range("A:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="#NV", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: What exactly does the following line do `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter`? Have you tried without it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filter function is not working like expected.

If yo use `Criteria1:="<>#N/A"` - the result seems to be ok.

But maybe you want to avoid NA at all. You can achieve this by using `=IFNA(` together with your `VLOOKUP` - applying a value that fits your needs and that can be filtered without problems (in German: `WENNNV(`)